# css - vertical scrolling and child escaping the container

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I want to use a jquery sortable to rearrange a list of items. I would like my list to be scrollable (vertically) while having the sortable handle popped out to the right of the list.

To prototype the markup, I've created a list, and positioned the handle so it pops out to the right, but as soon as I turn on vertical scrolling it scrolls on both axes and I loose my popover (it is hidden and you need to scroll it in to view while I really just want it to pop up outside the list).

Removing the overflow-y: scroll means it renders correctly but now I can't vertically scroll.

Is there any thing I can do to make this work?

(I've also tried using a sortable handle which is outside the sortable dom structure but sortable doesn't seem to like handles which aren't contained by the sortable item.)

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqfxp1eh/1/

```
<style>
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;

    /* adding this stops the .pop boxes from escaping the container */
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
#container li {
    border: 1px solid #00ff00;
    position: relative;
}
#container .pop {
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
    top: -10px;
    left: 130px;
    border: 2px solid #0000ff;
    position: absolute;
}

</style>
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2
                <div class="pop"></div>
            </li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the sortable side of the problem (the handle for sortable must be a descendant of the item to be dragged) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213899/jquery-ui-sortable-programmatically-set-item-being-dragged

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqfxp1eh/5/

move your `.pop` div out of the scrollable container, and position it against the new parent

I'm not sure about the 'sortable' part as the relevant code seems to be missing?

Comment: Thanks, to keep it simple I left out the sortable - I've also tried using a sortable handle which is outside the sortable dom structure (which is what you suggest) but sortable doesn't seem to like handles which aren't contained by the sortable item. So this breaks the sorting - unless there is an answer to that problem!